# saves all products of the cart list into firebase firestore | This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my shopping app, I am trying to save the order details (cart products) into Firstore and each product has a productId, productName, productImage, etc...

this **CartItemModel** class

```
@Parcelize
data class CartItemModel(

    val productId: String,
    val productImage: String,
    val productName: String,
    val freeCoupons: Long,
    val productPrice: String,
    val cuttedPrice: String,
    var productQuantity: Long,
    val maxQuantity: Long,
    val stockQuantity: Long,
    val offersApply: Long,
    val couponsApplied: Long,
    val inStock: Boolean,
    val qtyIDs: ArrayList<String>,
    var selectedCouponId: String?,
    var discountedPrice: String?,
) : Parcelable
```

before I tried to edit the `placeOrderDetails` method it saved only one product in this path

ORDERS >>> orderId like order_XYZ

and inside each order, there's `cart_summary` document that has the cart summary details like totalItems, totalItemsPrice, deliveryPrice, etc...

this the full **placeOrderDetails** before edits

```
   override suspend fun placeOrderDetails(
        orderID: String,
        cartItemModelList: ArrayList<CartItemModel>,
        address: String,
        fullName: String,
        pinCode: String,
        paymentMethod: String
    ): Flow<Resource<Boolean>> {
        val result = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())
        result.emit(Resource.Loading())

        val cartDataManager = CartDataManager()

        val cartSummary =cartDataManager.calculateTotalAmount(cartItemModelList)

        cartItemModelList.forEach {

                val orderDetails = hashMapOf<Any, Any>()

                orderDetails["ORDER ID"] = orderID
                orderDetails["PRODUCT ID"] = it.productId.toString()
                orderDetails["PRODUCT IMAGE"] = it.productImage.toString()
                orderDetails["PRODUCT NAME"] = it.productName.toString()
                orderDetails["USER ID"] = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!
                orderDetails["PRODUCT QUANTITY"] = it.productQuantity
                if (it.cuttedPrice.isNotEmpty()) {
                    orderDetails["CUTTED PRICE"] = it.cuttedPrice
                }

                orderDetails["PRODUCT PRICE"] = it.productPrice

                if (!it.selectedCouponId.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    orderDetails["COUPON ID"] = it.selectedCouponId!!
                }

                if (!it.discountedPrice.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    orderDetails["DISCOUNTED PRICE"] = it.discountedPrice!!
                } else {
                    orderDetails["DISCOUNTED PRICE"] = "0"
                }
                orderDetails["ORDER DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["PACKED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["SHIPPED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["DELIVERED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["CANCELLED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                orderDetails["ORDER STATUS"] = "ORDERED"
                orderDetails["PAYMENT METHOD"] = paymentMethod
                orderDetails["ADDRESS"] = address
                orderDetails["FULL NAME"] = fullName
                orderDetails["PIN CODE"] = pinCode
                orderDetails["FREE COUPONS"] = it.freeCoupons

                firestore.collection("ORDERS")
                    .document(orderID)
                    .set(orderDetails)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        val orderOtherDetails = hashMapOf<Any, Any>()
                        orderOtherDetails["Total Items"] = cartSummary.totalItems
                        orderOtherDetails["Total Items price"] = cartSummary.totalItemsPrice
                        orderOtherDetails["Delivery Price"] = cartSummary.deliveryPrice
                        orderOtherDetails["Total Amount"] = cartSummary.totalAmount
                        orderOtherDetails["Saved Amount"] = cartSummary.savedAmount
                        orderOtherDetails["PAYMENT STATUS"] = "not paid"
                        orderOtherDetails["ORDER STATUS"] = "Cancelled"

                        firestore.collection("ORDERS").document(orderID)
                            .collection("OtherDetails")
                            .document("cart_summary").set(orderOtherDetails)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                result.value = Resource.Success(true)

                            }.addOnFailureListener {
                                result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())

                            }

                    }.addOnFailureListener { ex ->
                        result.value = Resource.Error(ex.message.toString())

                    }

            }
        return result

    }
```

and this my try to edit it to saves all products not only one

```
  override suspend fun placeOrderDetails(
        orderID: String,
        cartItemModelList: ArrayList<CartItemModel>,
        address: String,
        fullName: String,
        pinCode: String,
        paymentMethod: String
    ): Flow<Resource<Boolean>> {
        val result = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())
        result.emit(Resource.Loading())

        val cartDataManager = CartDataManager()

        val cartSummary = cartDataManager.calculateTotalAmount(cartItemModelList)

        val orderDetailsList = mutableListOf<HashMap<Any, Any>>()

        for (cartItem in cartItemModelList) {
            val orderDetails = hashMapOf<Any, Any>()

            orderDetails["ORDER ID"] = orderID
            orderDetails["PRODUCT ID"] = cartItem.productId.toString()
            orderDetails["PRODUCT IMAGE"] = cartItem.productImage.toString()
            orderDetails["PRODUCT NAME"] = cartItem.productName.toString()
            orderDetails["USER ID"] = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!
            orderDetails["PRODUCT QUANTITY"] = cartItem.productQuantity

            if (cartItem.cuttedPrice.isNotEmpty()) {
                orderDetails["CUTTED PRICE"] = cartItem.cuttedPrice
            }

            orderDetails["PRODUCT PRICE"] = cartItem.productPrice

            if (!cartItem.selectedCouponId.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                orderDetails["COUPON ID"] = cartItem.selectedCouponId!!
            }

            if (!cartItem.discountedPrice.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                orderDetails["DISCOUNTED PRICE"] = cartItem.discountedPrice!!
            } else {
                orderDetails["DISCOUNTED PRICE"] = "0"
            }

            orderDetails["ORDER DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            orderDetails["PACKED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            orderDetails["SHIPPED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            orderDetails["DELIVERED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            orderDetails["CANCELLED DATE"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            orderDetails["ORDER STATUS"] = "ORDERED"
            orderDetails["PAYMENT METHOD"] = paymentMethod
            orderDetails["ADDRESS"] = address
            orderDetails["FULL NAME"] = fullName
            orderDetails["PIN CODE"] = pinCode
            orderDetails["FREE COUPONS"] = cartItem.freeCoupons

            orderDetailsList.add(orderDetails)
        }

        val batch = firestore.batch()

        for (i in orderDetailsList.indices) {
            val orderDetails = orderDetailsList[i]
            val documentRef = firestore.collection("ORDERS")
                .document(orderID).collection("Products")
                .document("Product$i")
            
            batch.set(documentRef, orderDetails)
        }

        batch.commit()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                val orderOtherDetails = hashMapOf<Any, Any>()
                orderOtherDetails["Total Items"] = cartSummary.totalItems
                orderOtherDetails["Total Items price"] = cartSummary.totalItemsPrice
                orderOtherDetails["Delivery Price"] = cartSummary.deliveryPrice
                orderOtherDetails["Total Amount"] = cartSummary.totalAmount
                orderOtherDetails["Saved Amount"] = cartSummary.savedAmount
                orderOtherDetails["PAYMENT STATUS"] = "not paid"
                orderOtherDetails["ORDER STATUS"] = "Cancelled"

                firestore.collection("ORDERS").document(orderID)
                    .collection("OtherDetails")
                    .document("order_summary")
                    .set(orderOtherDetails)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Success(true)
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { ex ->
                        result.value = Resource.Error(ex.message.toString())
                    }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { ex ->
                result.value = Resource.Error(ex.message.toString())
            }

        return result
    }
```

the problem is that after I make an order with the new `placeOrderDetails` I see this message in each document, it looks like the document is not completely created for some reason I don't know

> This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or
> snapshots Learn more

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @alex-mamo as I said I see this message in firebase and the document has not created
 This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots

Comment: Are you referring to the documents that are written in *italics*?

Comment: @alex-mamo yes correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see in the Firebase Console documents that are written in *italics*, it means that the Console is telling you that those documents don't exist. Those documents do not exist because you didn't create them at all. What you did do, was only reserve a document ID and create a sub-collection under it. So you see those documents in such a way, so you can navigate further to the sub-collections.

Please remember that in Cloud Firestore, documents, and sub-collections don't work like filesystem files and directories. If you create a sub-collection under a document, it doesn't implicitly create any parent document. Sub-collections are **not** tied in any way to a parent document.

If you want to have those documents in your result set, then you have to create at least a field inside the document that can hold a value of any type, even `null`.

Comment: so how to fix that in my code?

Comment: Very simple, before you write data in sub-collections, create the document first. That's it. Right after that,  you can add as many sub-collections as you want.